# Are there any raster methods in supervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

The SVM or ANN methods perform search of a surface which would separate the data points in a best way. This surface is returned in the vector or parametric form. Are there methods returning a spatial bitmap each voxel of which contains a numeric value defining a class for all points lying within this voxel?
Since I'm relatively new in machine learning I can't be quite sure that this was not done before or there are some reasons making this approach worthless for real data. I tried this approach with the adaptive grid in use. The below images were obtained by representing each data point by RBF and calculating influence of all such RBFs for each voxel.

[Tests with dummy dataset.](https://youtu.be/Cp7wI2BTWIs)
[Test with Zip Code dataset:](https://work.caltech.edu/homework/hw8.pdf) [rbf view f225;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTbvh.jpg) [voxel view f10;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaRwV.jpg) [voxel view f20;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0v14.jpg) [voxel view f30;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRDUp.jpg) [voxel view f50;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUqgO.jpg) [voxel view f100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4NkD.jpg)

Comment: You might want to ask this in a forum, this type of question may get an answer here, but is in many cases too broad or too opinion based. If you want to implement your mentioned method, but encounter problems, feel free to ask again.

Comment: @Loebl Thanks for the advice. Should I add the [forum] tag for that purpose? At this point, I would like to know if there have been any attempts in the raster approach. Or there are some reasons, making this approach meaningless for real data (e.g. exponential growth of the computational resources with number of dimensions requires an adaptive grid and complex algorithms for its processing).

Comment: I think the tag [tag:forum] is for questions regarding frameworks for developing forums, rather than indicating open discussion type of questions.

Comment: There is https://stats.stackexchange.com/ for questions about Machine Learning